# Participle as verbal adjective

Tags: tenses, past-participles, past-perfect

I came across the following:

> 1. As he had been deceived by his friends he lost all hope.
> 2. He was deceived by his friends and so he lost all hope.
> 3. Deceived by his friends, he lost all hope.
> 4. He lost all hope because he was deceived by his friends.

It was said that only sentence 3 has a participle in it. But all 4 has the word deceived,
Why is "Deceived by his friends, he lost all hope' is said to have participle?

Answer (score 2):

Each sentence has a participle: *deceived*

> In linguistics, a participle is a word that shares some characteristics (parts) of both verbs and adjectives.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) It can be used in compound verb tenses or voices (periphrasis), or as a modifier. A phrase composed of a participle and other words is a participle phrase.

saith [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle). But only one has a participial adjective: #3.

Comment: Can you explain how it is used as an adjective only in sentence 3 and is it simply a verb in rest of the sentences?

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't say it's a verb but a participle & part of a participial phrase in all cases. It shares characteristics with verbs & adjectives. The point is not what part of speech it is but how it functions, e.g., "rat race" is a compound noun composed of two nouns, but "rat" functions as an ADJ modifying race, not a noun. In S3, _deceived by his friends_ can be replaced by a non-verbal ADJ: _{Sick/Short/Ugly}, he lost all hope_. Ergo, _deceived_ functions as an ADJ in S3.

Comment: _He was deceived_ is an adjectival passive. _The door was **closed** during the noon hour_ is, according to **Wasow, Thomas (1977). ‘Transformations and the Lexicon.’ In: PW Culicover, T Wasow, & A Akmajian (eds.), _Formal Syntax._ NY: Academic Press. 327-360** a verbal passive {Search: [DOC] PASSIVE SYNTACTIC STRUCTURES}. "So-called adjectival passives have a sense of completed activity. In contrast, so-called verbal passives do not: door can still be open at noon." This doesn't define the part of speech of "closed", only the function: verbal vs. ADJ passive. Participles are ADJs.

Comment: He can still be _undeceived_, it seems, if his friends come clean & tell him the truth. If they're dead, however, they can't. For a definitive answer to your question, though, I'd suggest asking a professional linguistics, i.e., a Professor of Linguistics. John Lawler can probably answer your question definitively. & I won't claim that I fully understand this distinction that Wasow makes.

Answer (score 2):

In sentences 1,2 and 4 'deceived' is used as a verb in different tenses (past perfect in #1 and simple past in #2 and #4). It is used in passive voice so maybe that is why it may appear as a participial adjective. It is used as a participial adjective in #3. As such, it is the Head of Adjectivial Phrase (Deceived by his friends) and describes the Subject(he). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*Deceived* is still considered a past participle when used adjectivally.

Comment: Gunter Lorenz, in _Adjective Intensification_, (and many others) would not agree: 'By far the largest group of deverbal adjectives are those ending in -ed...20.2% of the data...' **And, showing that deverbalisation means conversion**: 'A deverbal noun, which is fully nominalized as a common noun and can take plurals, determiners, etc.

The police apprehended the people who carried out the shootings.
Note that since a verbal noun and a deverbal noun can sometimes have identical forms, this might be a bit confusing' (Mark Beadles)